# How do put the Time Dimension into order which I imported from an excel spreadsheet to SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I imported a Time Dimension from an excel spreadsheet to SQL Server.

The time dimension start date is 2005-07-01 to 2025-12-31 (aussie format)
Tha attributes is composed of

TimeKey Date    Date_Name   Year    Year_Name   Half_Year   Half_Year_Name  Quarter Quarter_Name  and all the way to fiscal attributes.

Anyways, when I created this TimeDim in the excel spreadsheet, it was in order, arranged properly from 2005-07-01 to 2025-12-31. I imported the spreadsheet in sql server then when I query using a select * from TimeDim.

The results are shuffled, dates are disarray.

Is there anyway to fix this? Im willing to truncate or drop the table then import the spreadsheet again so long it could fix the problem.

Many Thanks!!

Beau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which a table stores data is dependent on the `clustered index` that you define.

However, even if you define a clustered index for your date column, simply selecting the entire table does not guarantee that your data will be returned in that order.

The only way to guarantee data is selected in your desired order is by specifying the `ORDER BY` clause in your select statement.

Comment: Thank you. You have a point, however not every user knows order by TimeKey, most users (from accounting, finance dept) only know select * from TimeDim. What if I use the copy from excel then paste option in SQL Server? Would that work?

Comment: @BeauAlagan - even if that puts all the rows in the table in the order you want, it doesn't help: 1) the server isn't actually required to **keep** them stored in that order, 2) factors outside your control may change the 'current fastest' retrieval order - namely, if somebody else executes a query that results in a different ordering first, and the tables sits in memory, you may get that version!  The **ONLY SURE WAY** in SQL to get a specific order is to use `ORDER BY`,  _period_.  Anything else is just pure chance.

Comment: What I did is that I added a TimeKey which I set as the Primary Key.  Set it as Integer data type then I uncheck the NULL values. It's in the correct order now even without adding an ORDER BY statement. Let me know if you think there's a corresponding repercussion upon doing this. Thank you!

Comment: The fact that you can't guarantee order without specifying an ORDER BY. It might return in the desired order some of the time, maybe even most of the time, but it's not guaranteed. That's just the way it is.